Laptop sometimes hard reboots when scrolling in Twitter
This is one of the weirdest issues I have ever had:
When scrolling in Twitter in a browser, the laptop suddenly does a hard restart. This can happen multiple times a day or it can take a few days before it happens. I cannot provoke the error reliably.
It started around September 2024.

The laptop passes RAM test (24h)
It happens both in Firefox and in Brave
Scrolling can be done by touchpad or page-down. Same issue.
Same issue when using Intel or nVidia driver
No issue scrolling in, say, Instagram or in programs like LibreOffice
Laptop passes CPU stress test (8 hours of: s-tui stress; glxgears; VLC playing 2 video streams at 8Mbps each)
Running kernel 6.8.0-40 gives same issue

It is not due to cooling: The boot can happen a high load or a low load.
Is there any stress test I can run on the graphics cards? My best guess is that the scrolling sometimes triggers some sort of bug in the cards.
Maybe a new optimization introduced in August in X.org triggers this? Can I run a test of all X.org commands?
Can I ask X.org to be "less optimized"?
OS: Ubuntu GNU/Linux 24.04
Graphics cards:
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 740M] (rev a1)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)

journalctl -b -1 looks like it would if the power just disappeared: 100% normal and then nothing.

I'll assume that after a crash, journalctl -b -1 contains no relevant information?

This could be a HW issue as well. I wouldn't rule it out. Linux normally does NOT reboot on its own ever. It's a special system call.

@ArtemS.Tashkinov mulitple distros do a reboot when there is a kernel OOOPS, so that's not true.

I've yet to find a distro which reboots for kernel oopses, so "multiple" needs to have some solid data to back it up. By default the Linux kernel does not reboot for kernel oopses. It's looks like an asinine idea TBO because if it is happening the user won't even be able to see or report the issue. And as a Linux kernel bugzilla maintainer I get a lot of oopses from all kinds of distros all the time. No one has reported "sudden reboots" for the past five years or so. Maybe you're making this up.

Extending my prior comment... I assume your best bet on triggering the issue is some HTML5 browser stress/bench tool, like https://browserbench.org/Speedometer3.0/

@VlastimilBurián Trying the disabled accelleration now. If it it stable for a full weekend, I reckon we have found a workaround.

Any “Problem Detected” on chrome://gpu?

@PabloA No problems reported. But Brave seems solid when I disable accelerations.

@ArtemS.Tashkinov no, every time I say, "hey sorry Artem that's wrong", you get very hostile, and I can bring as many sources and point to facts as I want, it always ends up with you being aggressive to everyone, insulting multiple people, and then when someone steps in and asks you to be civil, you act the victim and claim people try to "cancel" you, which is patent nonsense. I stopped playing that game with you. For everyone else, I would, but you are so entitled to never being contradicted that you can very well look things up yourself, thankyou.

@OleTange Please respond to my query in my answer's edit... What version of Nvidia driver are you using?

Work-around
Disclaimer: Advice here will not revive your graphics chip, whatever it is wrong with it.
This looks to me like some rare GPU malfunction, which is why I advised in comments to turn off Chromium-based Brave browser's option which accelerates many things using graphics card.
The name of this option is: Use graphics acceleration when available
Let's see if it solves the problem, and if it does, take this as a CPU work-around, because it is your CPU, which will do the job entirely.
Here is Brave's screenshot with this toggle:

Good luck!

Further observation
Based on https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/details/196213/ the latest version of the official Nvidia driver for your card 740M is version 390, please include apt-cache policy nvidia-driver-390 to your question, me on Ubuntu-24-based Mint 22 can't find it anymore. It is possible it has been moved out of official repo, which could be a problem for you. I myself have never installed Nvidia driver directly from their web... It puzzles me, what version of the driver do you have installed now if not 390? Possible solution could be installing older version of Ubuntu if that version is not removed altogether.
Update your question, please.
